# Can a Gunsmith artificer put more barrels on his Thunder Cannon and use them in the same turn?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, unearthed-arcana, artificer, firearms

I am playing an Artificer with the Gunsmith specialization.  I am curious if I can add more barrels to my Thunder Cannon, and use them at once with the Thunder Monger class feature, [which states the following](https://media.wizards.com/2016/dnd/downloads/1_UA_Artificer_20170109.pdf#page=6):

> At 3rd level, you learn to channel thunder energy into your Thunder
>   Cannon. As an action, you can make a special attack with your Thunder
>   Cannon that deals an extra 1d6 thunder damage on a hit.
>
> This extra damage increases by 1d6 when you reach certain levels in
>   this class: 5th level (2d6), 7th level (3d6), 9th level (4d6), 11th
>   level (5d6), 13th level (6d6), 15th level (7d6), 17th level (8d6), and
>   19th level (9d6).

So would this apply to all barrels or just one?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## No, this would not work.

Assuming that this is referencing the [Artificer UA](https://media.wizards.com/2016/dnd/downloads/1_UA_Artificer_20170109.pdf)

### Additional barrels will not affect the game mechanics of the thunder cannon.

No where in the description of the thunder cannon is the number of barrels a factor nor is it specified.

The description of Thunder Cannon:

> At 1st level, you forge a deadly firearm using a combination of arcane magic and your knowledge of engineering and metallurgy.  This fire arm is called a Thunder Cannon.  It is a ferocious weapon that fires leaden bullets that can punch through armor with ease.  You are proficient with the Thunder Cannon.  The firearm is a two-handed ranged weapon that deals 2d6 piercing damage.  Its normal range is 150 feet, and its maximum range if 500 feet.  Once fired, it must be reloaded as a bonus action.  If you lose your Thunder Cannon, you can create a new one over the course of three days of work (eight hours each day) by expending 100 gp worth of metal and other raw materials.

The description does not specify the number of handles, triggers, sights, nor other accouterments that might impact the use a firearm as one might expect. 
It states the mechanical characteristics of the weapon which accounts for the whole of the design whatever it may be.

## Descriptive flavor

The aesthetics of the weapons and equipment a character is using should be mutable so long as they don't
 attempt to affect the mechanics in an end run around existing rules.

Answer (score -4):

I would say why not. It depends on the dm if he/she would allow it. I would say it costs more ammo and gp to add more on.

Comment: Welcome to RPGSE. Please take a look at the [tour], the [help], and [Answer] to get an idea for how to best contribute to a site that is constrained by the SE format.  As this site is not structured like a discussion forum, the question asker isn't soliciting opinions.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. Can you support your answer by citing evidence or experience?